# how to backtrack an ember application code

Tags: ember.js

How to understand an ember application code .

I want to backtrack where a variable is defined from web page to component.

example :

in web page `Title : "Wonder boy"`

in template it is mentioned as

```
 {{title-works field as |f|}}

     title = field.label

 {{#titel-works}}
```

but in the component for this template i am not able to find the varaible field nor field.label . can you please provide me any resource to understand how to backtrack a ember application from web front to variable . thanks .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your template looks a bit wrong. First the variable `f` is never used, next `title = field.label` is not `hbs` syntax and should literally print the string `"title = field.label"`. Is it maybe [emblem](http://emblemjs.com/)?

---

Now I just assume you actually use a variable as in `{{field.label}}`.

If you dont have the variable in the component it is passed down to it when the component is called.

So either by `{{your-component field=something}}` (old syntax) or `<YourComponent @field={{something}} />` (newer syntax).

This is indeed not very clear. That is the reason why `{{field}}` (and `{{field.something}}`) is deprecated in favor of either `{{this.field}}` (or `{{this.field.something}}`) when the data comes from the `component.js` (or `controller.js` in case of a route template) or `{{@field}}` (and `{{@field.something}}`) when it is passed down to the component, so it is *always* clear from where it comes.

---

Your best resource when debugging is the [ember-inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector). It can show you the component tree, so you know exactly from where your component is called and where to look.